# How to configure list of containers / apps for Docker to run?

Tags: docker

What is Docker's native mechanism for specifying to [Docker Engine](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/intro/) or [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/) the list of applications (and therefore, via `compose.yml`, the containers) to run on a given host?

### An illustrative scenario

I would like a given host to run all required containers for web applications **A** and **B**. Let's say **A** and **B** both require a database instance, but don't necessarily need separate instances. A and B each have separate Git repositories with a `compose.yml` defined, and containers avaiable.

### Current Solution: Use Compose

It is possible (and fairly straightforward) to create a `compose.yml` that specifies this configuration. In fact, a lot of Docker Compose's facilities seem explicitly created to support such scenarios. For example, we could specify:

- `app_a` **A** application container which connects to a database on a host named `db`.
- `app_b` **B** application container which connects to a database on a host named `db`.
- `database` container linked to both `app_a` and `app_b` as `db`
- `web` container that runs Apache/Nginx/etc. to do hostname-level HTTP proxying to the appropriate application container

All three are given a `restart:always` policy to ensure they're up, and the `docker` process is monitored using the OS' built-in monitoring tools (`systemd`, etc.)

### Why doesn't this seem as the intended solution?

Even though Docker Compose's toolset is perfectly suited to the task, Docker's documentation talks about *per-application* `compose.yml` configurations. Assuming that each application's `compose.yml` only specifies what's needed for that application, it seems awkward to specify that each application must start its own database, front-end web server, etc.

Presumably, in cases where each host only runs one application, this is not a problem.

### Other Docker tools

Looking into [Docker Machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/overview/), it seems to be a tool for *creating* hosts, rather than a per-host configuration tool. Similarly, Docker Swarm looks like it simplifies running operations on multiple hosts, rather than specifying what applications should run on a host.

It is, of course, possible that Docker considers the problem outside of its scope, and lets something like **Chef** or **Puppet** solve it. This would be frustrating given how perfectly Docker Compose is capable of describing and running the configuration otherwise.

Is there a better tool or mechanism to do this within Docker? Am I misunderstanding one of the above tools, and it solves this? Does Docker consider this out-of-scope?

Comment: While the documentation may say `per application`, there is nothing stop you from making the `docker-compose.yml` file multiple application.

Comment: No, and in fact that's the solution I'm currently using. I wanted to know if a) this is an intended use and b) whether Docker has a story for how to structure and where to store the `compose.yml` file(s). 

Do I make three separate files and store them in the app repositories? Do I just build one giant file and the rest is up to me? Can compose files require other compose files?